# capture but don't consume characters in string

Tags: python, regex

is it possible? for example the capture group in the pattern '(ab)' wouldn't consume characters in the string 'ab' somehow?

Comment: do you mean non-capturing group?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/what-is-a-non-capturing-group-what-does-do

Comment: Use lookaround instead

Comment: no i actually want to capture some characters - but then not consume the characters i just captured

Comment: @CertainPerformance yes that is what i want, but i think lookaround will discard the regex match? i want to keep the match

Comment: No, lookaround will not discard captured groups.

Comment: Can you give an example with the input, pattern, and desired output?

Answer (score 0):

A people have said in the comments a look ahead can capture but not consume. The following will capture the letter B into both capture groups even though it only exists once.

```
import re
matched = re.search('(?=(ab)).(bc)','12abc345')
if matched: print matched.groups()
```

**OUTPUT**

> ('ab', 'bc')

However for future posts it would be nice to see an attempt at some code or at least a minimum example of code that doesnt work for you. Example input and example output. So since you question lacked significant detail all people can do is post a generic example for you. If thats not enough for you to work from then you would need to update your question with more information about what you are trying to achieve.